# Numpy Matrix If/Else Classification?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Let's say I have a matrix M with 3 (or n) columns with negative/positive values:

```
M=[[-0.5,0.5,-1],
   [1,-0.5,-1],
   [-1,-1,-0.5],
   [0.5,1-,1],
   [1,0.5,1]]
```

I now want to classify each row by a condition, and create a fourth column with the result. The conditions are combinations of <0 and >0.

```
# Just an example of conditions
# The actual amount of conditions is 2^n with n being the amount of columns and 2 because there are variants (<0 and >0)
results = []
if row[0]<0 and row[1]>0 and row[2]>0:
    results.append(1)
elif row[0]>0 and row[1]>0 and row[2]>0:
    results.append(1)
elif row[0]<0 and row[1]<0 and row[2]<0:
    results.append(-1)
elif row[0]<0 and row[1]<0 and row[2]>0:
    results.append(-1)
else:
    results.append(1)
```

The "results" list is the column to be appended to M, so the output looks like this (the fourth value in each row is the result from the condition), so basically matrix M concatenated with results over axis 1.

```
 # Just example values, not matching the rules above
 M=[[-0.5,0.5,-1,1],
   [1,-0.5,-1,-1],
   [-1,-1,-0.5,-1],
   [0.5,1-,1,1],
   [1,0.5,1,1]]
```

What I'm looking for is a more efficient way than doing if/else statements for each row of the matrix. I was thinking that this is solvable somehow with matrix multiplication?! Appreciate any help.

Comment: I wonder in what context this has arisen, because: (1) I'm curious; (2) to make sure we're not dealing with an XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, from your description it seems that the element can't be zero, so let's assume that (without loss of generality).

There are `2**n` possible combinations of signs (`3**n` if we allow zeroes), where `n` is the number of columns. These you can encode in a vector, called `outcomes` below.

In what follows I show how we can apply matrix multiplication to solve this problem.

Let `M` be your input matrix:

```
In [36]: M
Out[36]:
array([[-0.5,  0.5, -1. ],
       [ 1. , -0.5, -1. ],
       [-1. , -1. , -0.5],
       [ 0.5,  1. , -1. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.5,  1. ]])

In [37]: m, n = M.shape
```

Now we:

- convert `M` into a binary matrix encoding the sign of each element;
- read out each row of the result as if it were a base-2 number.

This gives, for each row of `M`, the index of the corresponding outcome:

```
In [40]: outcome_index = np.matmul(M > 0, [2**i for i in range(n)])

In [41]: outcome_index
Out[41]: array([2, 1, 0, 3, 7])
```

Finally, we use the index to compute the new column:

```
In [42]: outcomes[outcome_index]
Out[42]: array([-1, -1,  1,  1, -1])
```

Adding the column to `M` is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

P.S. I've used the following `outcomes` vector in this example:

```
In [43]: outcomes
Out[43]: array([ 1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1])
```

P.P.S. I've just noticed that my code reads out the base-2 number right-to-left instead of the more natural (to me) left-to-right. That's not really a problem and is easy to change (also left as an exercise for the reader).